# Database updates made in TestNG @DataProvider not rolling back

Tags: java, spring-boot, testng, spring-transactions, testng-dataprovider

In my automated tests, I am wanting to use a @DataProvider to 1.) perform some database updates, in order to guarantee the state of the data that I am about to test, and 2.) return the test data that will work in such an environment.

What I am finding is that the updates are made successfully in the @DataProvider body, then the updates made in my test are successful, all assertions pass, and then the testing updates are rolled back. However, the @DataProvider updates are NOT rolled back and are left after the test has completed.

Is there a way to roll back database updates made inside of a @DataProvider body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is simillar to [How to delete data only after all tests, based on inputs from data provider, are run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309689/how-to-delete-data-only-after-all-tests-based-on-inputs-from-data-provider-are/44317210#44317210)

It's answer is applicable for you.

---

**UPDATE**

In your case `@DataProvider` is a bad option. In TestNG you can work only with results provided by `@DataProvider` and they are running before suite. You have several ways to solve your problem.

- Create a listener which is connecting DB transactions with related `@DataProvider` result. It has to implement `ITestListener`. On each test finish event your listener will rollback required transactions.
- Second option, is like the first one, but your `@DataProvider` does nothing with DB, it's just provide some inputs, which should be handled by `@BeforeMehtod` and `@AfterMethod`, updated and rollbacked respectively. In that case all your context could be stored in particular test class.
- Also you can create a new annotation that using principles descibed above, providing and managing your buisness entities.

Comment: That is true, but there are a few problems with that solution. 1.) Some data is inserted and some data is updated. The updated data cannot simply be deleted, it must be reverted back to its previous state. 2.) I don't want my team to have to remember to write "undo" code for every update they make inside a @DataProvider. Rolling back a transaction is much simpler.

Is there a way to transactionally roll back updates made in @DataProvider?